# Materialize - text overlapping div

Tags: html, materialize

https://jsfiddle.net/cpfm27q3/

The columns 'latest news' text are overlapping eachother as seen in jsfiddle.

I'd like to have the text jump to a new line.

```
         <div class="col s12 l3">
          <div class="col s3 l12">
            <h6 class="red-text">Latest News</h6>
            <ul class="latest-collection">
              <li class="latest-collection-item">Teswtttttttttdddddddddddt</li>
              <li class="latest-collection-item">Teswtttttttttdddddddddddt</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col s3 l12">
            <h6 class="red-text">Latest News</h6>
            <ul class="latest-collection">
              <li class="latest-collection-item">Teswtttttttttdddddddddddt</li>
              <li class="latest-collection-item">Teswtttttttttdddddddddddt</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="col s3 l12">
            <h6 class="red-text">Latest News</h6>
            <ul class="latest-collection">
              <li class="latest-collection-item">Teswtttttttttdddddddddddt</li>
              <li class="latest-collection-item">Teswtttttttttdddddddddddt</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text isn't wrappable text, so you'd probably need to add overflow: hidden or word-wrap: break-word to your class latest-collection-item